# Error in center-focus length of an ellipse

Tags: quadratics, conic-sections

I have an equation of ellipse in the form:
$$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0.$$

I would to calculate the semi-axis major and minor and the center coordinates of the ellipse.

I found these answers here from Osmund Francis's [answer 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/801572) and [answer 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/820896/257270)

I plugged everything in formulae in a simple JS program. Everthing is right but the semi-minor axis length is wrong (I used Geogebra to compare the result), and as the answers of Osmund Francis tell, semi-minor axis length depends on s *the distance center-focus* and other things.
It seems that there is a problem in $s$.

Could someone correct that or give me a garanty that it is right if I am wrong?

JS code is [at service](https://jsfiddle.net/xakq4d4x/) if someone would looks at.
thanks

Comment: Please refer to [**this**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839510/how-to-get-the-correct-angle-of-the-ellipse-after-approximation/1840050#1840050) for your reference.