# Hyperbola asymptotes from conic general equation

Tags: conic-sections

If I have the coefficients of the following equation:

$$AX^2 + BXY + CY^2 + DX + EY + F = 0$$

And I know it's a hyperbola, how can I get the equations for the asymptotes  with respect to the coefficients `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, and `F`?

i.e. similar to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616645/determining-the-major-minor-axes-of-an-ellipse-from-general-form/820896#820896), except that question deals with properties of ellipses from the general equation instead of hyperbolas.

Comment: What sort of equation(s) are you looking for? Deriving the general conic that represents the two asymptotes, for instance, is quite straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First find the *centre* of the conic.

This is the point $(u,v),$ such that the equation of the conic can be rewritten as
$$A(X-u)^2+B(X-u)(Y-v)+C(Y-v)^2+F'=0.$$
For the conic to be a hyperbola, the quadratic part has to factor
into distinct linear factors over $\Bbb R$:
$$AX^2+BXY+CY^2=(R_1X+S_1Y)(R_2X+S_2Y).$$

Then the asymptotes are
$$R_i (X-u)+S_i(Y-v)=0$$
($i=1$, $2$).

Comment: Looks good. I just need to figure out the degenerate cases and how to handle them...

Comment: @amWhy: I'm fine with the edit not being approved, but could you verify if the steps I wrote were correct? I'd like to make sure I understood it right.

Comment: @amWhy: hope I don't sound rude, but I'll just accept that the steps *were* correct, and that they were edited out for brevity.

Comment: @harry Do not edit to write what  you wish the OP had written.  Suggested edits, and edits in general, should be limited to correcting spelling errors, grammar, or adding mathjax.  Do not ever edit to put words into a user's mouth.  If you see an error, notify the asker or the answerer in a polite comment, suggesting an improvement.  I wouldn't, if I were you, assume your steps were correct.  This was not your question, and it is not our job to evaluate what an editor thinks is correct.  Stick to realms of suggested edits.

Comment: @amWhy: Right, got it, sorry if I breached etiquette. I suppose I was treating individual people's answers more like wikis. Won't happen again.

Comment: No problem, @harry.  You should feel free, whenever you suspect an error, comment to the asker or answerer.  Also feel free to answer a question, if you feel an answer is missing something.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The equation of a hyperbola whose asymptotes have equations $ax+by+c=0$ and $dx+ey+f=0$ can be written as:
$$
(ax+by+c)(dx+ey+f)=g.
$$
You only need then to expand the above equation and compare the coefficient of the resulting polynomial with $A\dots F$ to obtain $a\dots g$.

In practice, to avoid redundancies, it's convenient to divide the equation of the hyperbola by $A$ (if $A\ne0$) and thus set $a=d=1$, to get a system of five equations in five unknowns.

Comment: Sorry to ask like this, but the person whose answer is accepted hasn't been online in a while. Could you elaborate on what happens in the second step (the factorising into linear factors part)?

Comment: @harry Just expand and equate the coefficients of the same monomials: $A=ad$, $B=ae+bd$, $C=be$, and so on. Then solve for $a$, $b$, $c$, ... If $A\ne0$ you can set $A=a=d=1$ without loss of generality.

Comment: @harry I realise now that you are asking about the other answer... Factoring $AX^2+BXY+CY^2$ is a standard exercise: divide by $Y^2$ and factor the resulting quadratic polynomial in $X/Y$.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. It's because $B^2-4AC$ for hyperbolas is always greater than 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The asymptotes of a hyperbola are the tangents at its intersections with the line at infinity. The matrix of this general equation is $$Q = \begin{bmatrix}A&\frac B2&\frac D2\\\frac B2&C&\frac E2\\\frac D2&\frac E2&F\end{bmatrix}$$ and the line at infinity is $\mathscr l = [0,0,1]^T$. Let $\mathscr l_\times$ be the “cross product matrix” of $\mathscr l$. We can compute the hyperbola-line intersection by finding a value of $\alpha$ that makes $$\mathscr l_\times^TQ\mathscr l_\times+\alpha\mathscr l_\times = \begin{bmatrix}C&-\alpha-\frac B2&0\\\alpha-\frac B2&A&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ a rank-one matrix. This occurs when the principal $2\times2$ minor vanishes, which leads to a quadratic equation in $\alpha$ with solutions $\pm\frac12\sqrt{B^2-4AC}$. Taking the positive root gives the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}C&-\frac12\left(B+\sqrt{B^2-4AC}\right)&0 \\ -\frac12\left(B^2-\sqrt{B^2-4AC}\right)&A&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ The two intersection points are the row and column corresponding to any nonzero element of this matrix. For example, if $C\ne0$, then the two points are $\mathbf p_1 = \left[C,-\frac12\left(B+\sqrt{B^2-4AC}\right),0\right]^T$ and $\mathbf p_2 = \left[C,-\frac12\left(B-\sqrt{B^2-4AC}\right),0\right]^T$, the projective equivalents of the asymptotes’ direction vectors, with corresponding tangents $\mathscr m_i = Q\mathbf p_i$. The implicit Cartesian equations of the lines that these vectors represent are $[x,y,1]\mathscr m_i=0$, or $[x,y,1]Q\mathbf p_i=0$.

Comment: Hello @amd, is it possible to get the semi-major axis, eccentricity and orientation of major axis of this hyperbola from conic matrix?

Answer (score 1):

In matrix form the equation is $$x^TAx+2b^Tx+c=0$$ where $A$ is $2\times2$ symmetric.

It can be centered with

$$(x+A^{-1}b)^TA(x+A^{-1}b)-b^TA^{-T}A^Tb+c=y^TAy+c'=0.$$

Then, by diagonalizing $A$,

$$y^TP\Lambda P^{-1}y+c'=z^T\Lambda z+c'=0.$$

For an hyperbola, the Eigenvalues have opposite signs and the reduced equation is

$$\lambda_uu^2-\lambda_vv^2=(\sqrt{\lambda_u}u+\sqrt{\lambda_v}v)(\sqrt{\lambda_u}u-\sqrt{\lambda_v}v)=-c'.$$

The two factors are the asymptotes, and in the original coordinates

$$x=P^{-1}z-A^{-1}b.$$