Find the rotation angle of an Ellipse for a given point with horizontal tangent
Suppose I have an ellipse centered at (0,0), defined by its major axis a, minor axis b, and a vertical extremum point (x0,y0). Is there a way to determine the rotation angle θ of the ellipse?


do you only know $(x_0,y_0)$?

If you were to work from the general form of a conic section, it would be pretty darn tedious: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616645/determining-the-major-minor-axes-of-an-ellipse-from-general-form.
